# googleapis geocode APPROXIMATE and wrong location

Tags: google-maps, location, google-api, geocoding

The following request results in wrong (approx.) coordinates (about 600 meters from correct location):
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Garbatyplatz+2+13187+Berlin&sensor=true

```
=> "lat" : 52.57206610, "lng" : 13.41266040
www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=52.57206610%2C+13.41266040
```

But if you look for the address directly in google maps, it is correct:
https://www.google.de/maps/preview#!q=Garbatyplatz+2+13187+Berlin

Anybody an idea why the result is approx. and so much off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Geocoder isn't finding that address, it is returning the result for the partial match: 
[ 0 ]: 13187 Berlin, Germany (52.5720661, 13.41266040000005)

What Google Maps is showing is a "place" result:
[Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps?q=Garbatyplatz+2+13187+Berlin&hq=Garbatyplatz+2&hnear=13187+Berlin&t=m&z=15)

That can be found using the [Places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Garbatyplatz+2+13187+Berlin&place=1&addr2=Garbatyplatz%202%2013187%20Berlin&geocode=2)